# Variable in while loop being read from unexpected source

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to compare the content of `file2` with that of `file1` and based on that I need to take some action.

But when I try to take input from user (in variable `answer`) whether to start or not, the program does not wait for user input and takes value assigned to variable `line` automatically.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line;
do 
var=`grep $line file1.txt`

if [ -z "$var"] 
then 
    echo "$line is not running"
    echo "Do you want to start? (Y/N)"
    read answer
    if [ "$answer" = 'Y' ] || [ "$answer" = 'N' ]
    then
        if [ "$answer" = 'Y' ]
        then
        (some action)
        else
        (action)
        fi
    else
    (action)
    fi
fi

done < file2
```

Comment: Your code has some typos: `whileread` and the closing backtick is missing. In addition, you wrote `answer` instead of `$answer` in the second conditional.

Answer (score 2):

You redirect stdin for the `while` loop to `file2`. So inside the loop, `stdin` is redirected and a `read` will read from the file, not from the terminal.

With `bash`, you can easily fix that by using a different file descriptor:

```
while read -r -u3 line; do
  echo "$line"
  read -p "Continue? " yesno
  if [[ $yesno != [Yy]* ]]; then break; fi
done 3<file2
```

The `-u3` command-line flag to `read` causes it to read from fd 3, while the `3<file2` redirection redirects fd 3 to `file` (opening `file` for reading).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to the excellent answer offered by @rici, this time not requiring bash:

```
while read -r line <&3; do
  echo "$line"
  printf "Continue? " >&2
  read yesno
  case $yesno in
    [Yy]*) : ;;
    *) break ;;
  esac
done 3<file2
```

Using `read <&3` reads from FD 3, just as the bash extension `read -u 3` would do.