# POSIX compliant shell command for reading co-process stdout with timeout

Tags: linux, shell, unix, posix, aix

I am having this some kind of simple program where i pass the cmds read to another co-proces shell and read the stdout and displaying it , the read -t(timeout) is needed otherwise the loop gets stuck in the read, waiting for other process to send output to stdout, but the problem is read -t is not POSIX compliant and doesn't work on AIX or Solaris, Is there any other way I can make it work so that it works on all POSIX compliant platforms ? This solution http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.shell/read-timeout/498289 work for reading from the terminal but not from the co-process, not sure how to adapt to this situation ?

```
#!/bin/ksh
ksh |&
while read INPUT
do
 echo $INPUT
 print -p "$INPUT"
 while read -t 1 -p OUT
        do
                case $OUT in
                        $)
                                break ;;
                        *)
                                echo "${OUT}" ;;
                esac
        done
done
```

Comment: You must use `1 file descriptor` per loop. You can't have nested `read` statements both reading from `stdin` (i.e. `fd0`).  There are examples of reading from 2 file descriptors on this site. You will need to redirect a file to another file descriptor and then use `read -u #` where `#` is the new file descriptor number. You can assign a second instance of `stdin` (`0`) to `3` with `3<&0` and use `read -u 3 ...`

Comment: not sure if i understood any sample code will be helpful

Comment: Something like [while loop reading from fd 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842455/variable-in-while-loop-being-read-from-unexpected-source/28865971#28865971)

Comment: I don't get your problem. Your script does not use the POSIX shell `/bin/sh` - it uses the `/bin/ksh`. IOW, it already requires the `ksh`, a non-POSIX shell. Go on using the `ksh` specific functions and simply state that your application requires the `ksh`.  Literally every commercial *nix system (including AIX) has `ksh` pre-installed. And it is usually one command away on Linux systems.